# RS232 is a protocol or Interfacing standard

Tags: embedded

UART and RS232 are same protocols or not?If yes then why we called RS232 is a interfacing standard.Is the Protocol and interfacing standard same?

Comment: [A UART isn't a protocol.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter)

Answer (score 8):

UART (universal asynchronous receiver/transmitter) refers to a hardware device for serial data transmission where the timing is recovered from the data frame.  A frame has a start bit, data bits, optionally a parity bit, and a stop bit (or bits).  The start but synchronises the bit sampling for the rest of the frame.

RS-232 refers to a series of related standards for the electrical interface and signalling of a specific serial interface.  While the output of a UART will be at the logic level of the UART device, RS-232 defines specific voltage levels, so when a UART is used to implement an RS-232 interface, an RS-232 level line driver is required. RS-232 line levels are bi-polar (the logic states are negative and positive voltage), while UART will have logic levels of zero and some positive voltage.

Full RS-232 includes additional signal lines apart from serial Tx/Rx some of which (such as flow control) may be provided by a UART and others such *ring indicator* that would be provided by other logic such as GPIO. A minimal RS232 implementation (three-wire mode) requires Tx, Rx and Ground.

A UART might be used for other interfaces such as RS-422, RS-485, and for short distance chip-to-chip communication may be connected directly UART to UART.  So UART and RS-232 are certainly not the same thing.

In the [OSI 7-layer model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) for communications, RS-232 covers only [Layer 1 - Physical Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_1:_physical_layer).  A UART is merely a means of implementing part of such a physical layer.

So with respect to "protocols"  RS-232 is a pysical layer protocol only - it does not define any semantics to the data being transmitted. A UART is not a protocol at all, but a digital electronic device for implementing a number of types of physical layer communications.

Answer (score 4):

UART is a piece of translation hardware, not a protocol. they can work with many serial/parallel communications protocols including but not limited to RS232

Answer (score 2):

RS232 is an electrical standard, not a protocol.  Just like RS485, rs422 and others, all of which can carry the same serial protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The output of an UART are UART frames. Frames are defined at the OSI layer2 Data Link Layer. So RS2-232 is a little bit more than Layer1 OSI.
RS485 and RS422 are working on LAye1 only because the rest of the communication will done by upper layer protocols such as Modbus or PROFIBUS for example (Layer2 and Layer7)

Peter The Netherlands

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer